# How to add the time in one column in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a problem about getting all the data's in one column and will add it by user id.

I Retrieve the data's by this query

```
SELECT uid, date, timein, timeout,TIMEDIFF(timein, '08:00:00') as DATE_DIFF 
 FROM sample_tbl 
WHERE date >= '2015-11-01' 
  AND date <= '2015-11-15' 
  AND uid IN (32,61,53,54,62,57,55,58,34,60,63,59) 
  AND timein > '08:00:00'
```

The Output

[image]

My Problem is How can I add them? for example uid = 32 should be

`uid = 32 and DATE_DIFF = "00:11:00"`

I also tried `Group By uid` and `SUM()` or is it possible?

Comment: So what exactly did not worked with GROUP By and SUM() approach?

Comment: Hi @Anton i think SUM() gives me the decimal. Do you have any idea on How can I add the Time?

Comment: can you please provide sample table and data? a tip on debugging queries which deal with patterned data: experiment with just one row, if you get the correct output with one, it should work on all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok iv'e read about `SUM()` function and add this to my query `SUM(minute(TIMEDIFF(timein, '08:00:00')))` and Group it by ID

```
SELECT uid, date, timein, timeout,SUM(minute(TIMEDIFF(timein, '08:00:00'))) as Total_late 
FROM sample_tbl 
WHERE date >= '2015-11-01' 
AND date <= '2015-11-15' 
AND uid IN (32,61,53,54,62,57,55,58,34,60,63,59) 
AND timein > '08:00:00' 
GROUP BY uid
```